# VB.net Perform task at scheduled Date

Tags: vb.net

So, i want to change picturebox backcolor automatically at a specific time chosen from a DateTimePicker.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If DateTime(Now) = Stringpass4 Then
    A1.backcolor = color.lighblue
    End If
```

Comment: Please visit the Help Center and learn what constitutes an acceptable and valid question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use = to compare times like that. The chances you will hit the exact millisecond needed for the times to be considered equal is very very unlikely

Instead make your test using >

```
If(DateTime.Now > mydatetimepicker.Value)
  a1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
End If
```

Make your timer tick at 1000 millisecond interval. It means that within a second of the world time rolling past the time in the picker, the screen will change. If you need more accuracy, make the timer tick more often. It is better to make the timer tick not very often though, so don't set the interval to 1ms- set it to as long as possible so that your requirement is still met. Like if you're making a clock for your kid to know he can only get out of bed when the screen goes blue, that would be fine at 10 seconds interval or something. If you're timing an industrial process that needs to show a change within half a second make the interval half of that requirement , so 250ms